# how to connect to a created user in oracle db through jdbc?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

i have this code

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XEPDB1","system","oracle");
```

now this code works fine, but what i want to do is to connect to a user that i created using oracle sql developer where the username is "user" and the password is "1111".
[image: this is my user inside the "other users"]

Comment: `"system"` is the username and `"oracle"` is the password. eplace those with `"user"` and `"1111"`. And while you're at it, maybe review the auth settings; those passwords are useless (everybody knows these). Perhaps oracle DB requires username/passwords to be set; more robustly designed DB systems such as postgres can be configured to allow anything from localhost and nothing from outside of it, without involving pointless passwords.

Comment: @rzwitserloot thats where the problem is, i did exactly that but i get this  ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
and i cant currently switch to a different database. i also checked the username and password, made a new user, but it wont connect

Comment: The problem isn't java, it's oracleDB - and I don't think this is the right SO (even if it is - you haven't provided sufficient information; your question then boils down to: "How does OracleDB auth work?" which is a bit too broad for SO I'm afraid). DBs can be configured to allow a certain user to only connect via local pipe (JDBC connects via TCP/IP), your password might not be '1111', and a million other explanations come to mind.

Comment: The SQL Developer one seems to be connecting to the CON (container) DB while the JDBC URL seems to be trying to connect to the pluggable datase (XEPDB1) within the container.

Comment: @rzwitserloot i know i didnt provide sufficient information because i wanted a quick general solution. but since the obvious solution doesnt work there is absolutely something wrong with how i set up the database. i can continue without connecting to a user because the project im developing is not serious. thank you for helping anyways

Comment: @Gary-Myers i changed the XEPDB1 to xe, same problem